# Conditionally displaying multiple Lightning Datatables

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have an issue as i want to be able to conditionally create a a new Lightning Datatable based off an selection on another datatable.

to break it down.

1. i have a datatable on account with related accounts.
2. when a user selects on one of these related accounts they can add related statements objects to these realated accounts.
3. from there they can save that record and a another datatable appears with the rows being these statements and they are grouped by the realated acocunts.
4. my issue is the statements all appear on one datatable.
5. is there any way i can display separate tables based on the statements related accounts?

I can post my code just need ideas haha.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just put the account groupings into an array, and then iterate over the array as new tables:

```
relatedAccounts = [
  { accountName: 'abc', Id: '001...', statements: [ { ... } ] },
  { accountName: 'def', Id: '001...', statements: [ { ... } ] },
  ...
]
```

Then:

```
<template for:each={relatedAccounts} for:item="account">
  <lightning-datatable 
    key={account.Id} 
    data={account.statements} 
    columns={statementColumns} 
    key-field="Id">
  </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Feel free to add separators or whatever to make it look as nice as you want.

Comment: gotcha, and this should work with imperitve calls right? i dont do @wires all database calls

Comment: @AlexJader Yes, the data structures are still the same.

Comment: ok i did this, howver it is givng me separate datatable per each row. if rows have the same account linked, i dont want separate tables for them but have them be in a table together if that makes sense.